# Is it good to copy the array in each recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am actually doing the `Daily Coding Problem #2`

I believe I have the result and I used it with recursion but I am wondering if it's good that I passed the `arr` in each recursion?  Will passing it cause more memory or time?

The coding problem question is

> Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element at index i of the new array is the product of all the numbers in the original array except the one at i.
>
> For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output
> would be [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]. If our input was [3, 2, 1], the
> expected output would be [2, 3, 6]

My code looks like

```
const multiply_without_index = (arr, index, result) => {
    result = result || [];
    index = index || 0;
    if(index === arr.length) return result;
    
    const copy_arr = [...arr];
    copy_arr.splice(index, 1);
    let total = 1;
    for(let n of copy_arr){
        total *= n;
    }
    result.push(total);
    index++;

    return multiply_without_index(arr, index, result);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an easy mathematical approach to solve this as I have solved this question. Coming to your question, you don't need to create another array i.e `copy_arr` as you are already passing index. You can directly check if `i`===`index` in `for-of` loop and skip that iteration.

```
const multiply_without_index = (arr, index, result) => {
    result = result || [];
    index = index || 0;
    if(index === arr.length) return result;
    
    let total = 1;
    for(let [i,n] of arr.entries()){
    if(i===index)
    continue;
        total *= n;
    }
    result.push(total);
    index++;

    return multiply_without_index(arr, index, result);
}
```

**Spoiler Alert** Give below is the second approach which I used while solving the same question.

```js
//log(a*b*c)=loga+logb+logc
let a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
let prod=a.reduce((acc,val)=>{return acc*val},1)
let res=[]
a.map((val)=>{
res.push(Math.floor(Math.exp(Math.log(prod)-Math.log(val))))
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to write a complex solution using several smaller solutions

Here's `mult` -

```js
const mult = ([ n = 1, ...more ]) =>
  more.length
    ? n * mult(more)
    : n
    
console.log(mult([]))          // 1
console.log(mult([ 5 ]))       // 5
console.log(mult([ 5, 4 ]))    // 20
console.log(mult([ 5, 4, 3 ])) // 60
```

And `drop` -

```js
const drop = (t = [], pos = 0) =>
  [ ...t.slice(0, pos), ...t.slice(pos + 1) ]
  
const m =
  [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  
console.log(drop(m, 0)) // [ "b", "c" ]
console.log(drop(m, 1)) // [ "a", "c" ]
console.log(drop(m, 2)) // [ "a", "b" ]
console.log(drop(m, 3)) // [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Now `multIndex` is a specialization of `mult` and `drop` -

```
const multIndex = (t = [], pos = 0) =>
  pos >= t.length
    ? []
    : [ mult(drop(t, pos)), ...multIndex(t, pos + 1) ]
    
console.log(multIndex([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]))
// [ 120, 60, 40, 30, 24 ]
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const drop = (t = [], pos = 0) =>
  [ ...t.slice(0, pos), ...t.slice(pos + 1) ]
  
const mult = ([ n = 1, ...more ]) =>
  more.length
    ? n * mult(more)
    : n
    
const multIndex = (t = [], pos = 0) =>
  pos >= t.length
    ? []
    : [ mult(drop(t, pos)), ...multIndex(t, pos + 1) ]
    
console.log(multIndex([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
// [ 120, 60, 40, 30, 24 ]
```

---

You could write `multIndex` without recursion too, using `Array.prototype.map` -

```js
const multIndex = (t = []) =>
  t.map((_, pos) => mult(drop(t, pos)))

console.log(multIndex([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
// [ 120, 60, 40, 30, 24 ]
```

---

And another approach for `multIndex` is entirely different -

```js
const mult = (vs = []) =>
  vs.reduce((r, v) => r * v, 1)

const multIndex = (vs = []) =>
  vs.map(v => mult(vs) / v)
  
console.log(multIndex([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]))
// [ 120, 60, 40, 30, 24 ]
```

---

Lastly a recursive form that is extremely efficient and guarantees not to overflow the stack! or the max-safe integer! Compute the product of 1,000 numbers in your browser below -

```js
const recur = (...vs) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => vs.values() })
  
const loop = (f, ...init) =>
{ let r = f(...init)
; while (r && r.recur === recur) r = f(...r)
; return r
}

const mult = (m = []) =>
  loop
    ( (r = 1n, pos = 0) =>
        pos >= m.length
          ? r
          : recur(r * m[pos], pos + 1)
    )

const multIndex = (m = []) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = []
      , pos = 0
      , p = mult(m)
      ) =>
      pos >= m.length
        ? r
        : recur
            ( (r.push(p/m[pos]), r)
            , pos + 1
            , p
            )
    )
    
const numbers = Array.from(Array(1000), (_, i) => BigInt(i) + 1n)
// [ 1, 2, 3, ..., 1000 ]

console.time("multIndex")
const result = multIndex(numbers)
console.timeEnd("multIndex")
document.body.innerHTML = result.join("<br>")
// multIndex: 12.260ms
```

This computes over 2.5 MB of unique products in less than 20 ms -

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your particular question, adding the array as a parameter in the function should not be a big deal. JavaScript passes array (i.e. object) arguments by reference, so essentially you are adding a few more bytes of memory (corresponding to the reference value) to the stack each time the recursion goes down another level.

As to the solution to the problem, note that you should be able to do this without recursion, in O(n) complexity (as suggested by kapil when he says there's an easy mathematical solution to this).

Answer (score 0):

Passing array in the recursive function should not be an issue because only the reference gets passed each time and the memory allocated will be the same. But the splice operation that you do is another loop operation done internally. You can do this without using recursion and splice operations.

If the numbers in the array going to be non-zero, we can do it in *O(2n)* complexity. Check **getProductSeries** function.

If not, check **getProductSeries2** function (which is commented) which is written in *O(n^2)* complexity.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let getProductSeries = (arr)=>{
  let multiplyTotal = arr.reduce((total, currentValue)=> total * currentValue);
  return arr.map((num)=>multiplyTotal/num);
}

console.log(getProductSeries(arr));
/*
let getProductSeries2 = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((num, index) => {
     let total = 1;
     arr.forEach((num, inner_index)=>{
        if(inner_index !== index){
           total *= arr[inner_index];
        }
     });
     return total;
  });
}
console.log(getProductSeries2(arr));
*/
```